# Use Json variable between two PowerShell steps

Tags: json, powershell, azure-devops

In an Azure Devops Pipeline I need to pass over a Json variable from a Powershell script in step 1 to another Powershell script in step 2. The double quotes of the Json variable seem to be messing things up. Escaping them also does not seem to work.

Here the 2 steps:

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Debug -> Step 1'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |      
      $json = [pscustomobject]@{ prop1 = "value1"; prop2 = "value2" } | ConvertTo-Json
      Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MYVAR]$json"

- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: 'Debug -> Step 2'
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo $env:MYVAR
```

This results in:

[image]

Any idea how I can pass an object (in Json) to another step?

Comment: If creating a _single-line_ representation of your JSON solves the problem, add `-Compress` to the `ConvertTo-Json` call.

Comment: Glad to hear it, Bastiaan. Because I wasn't sure if my solution was the right one, I started out with a comment, but I'm glad someone has posted a proper answer since.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logging command `##vso[task.setvariable]` can only accept a single line string. You need to use `-Compress` to convert the json object to a single line string. See below example:

```
$json = [pscustomobject]@{ prop1 = "value1"; prop2 = "value2" } | ConvertTo-Json -Compress
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=MYVAR]$json "
```